# Integrated commands within google assistant's SDK

Tags: python, sdk, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm here to clarify an amusing idea I had but couldn't find some way to do it... Yet.

I'm diving into GAssistant SDK, my idea is to have integrated commands using hotkeywords so we can develop a way to talk with the device and have much better answers for each user separately.

Example: "Ok Google, A5" **If we could make GAssistant understands that A5 it's the same as saying** "set an alarm for me at".

So we could answer with the hour. But **what if we could say more?**.

**There's any way at all of integrating more than 1 command in some action?**

Example: Not only waking me up at 7AM but already with a Hello and saying the Weather + Some Tech News or something I could ADD to the **A5** command?

It would be like scheduling a command, like set an alarm for 7AM, say the weather at 7 am and the news at 7 am.

You guys have any idea how we could get to this? I didn't find anything about it, trying to reach some Google's Assistant SDK team with those questions as well.

Thank you guys, cya!

Answer (score 0):

Assistant shortcuts allow you to map your own custom phrases to other phrases the Assistant understands. This will allow you to do some basic use cases similar to the ones you outline above.

Check out this help site for [Assistant shortcuts](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7390802) for instructions on how to set them up.